# Android remote webview list of active sites is empty

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, remote-debugging

I do some automated tasks an android over adb commands, at one part i need to access a webview inside the app and control it. Until now i did these things:

1. I get the running webview processes with this command `adb shell cat /proc/net/unix`
2. For each process i do a protforwarding with this command `adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:webview_devtools_remote_25866`
3. I do a get request to `http://localhost:9222/json` and get an array with webvies accessible over this proccess (so i clould check the title and the attaced state to find the right one)

My problem is now that since a few days I always get an empty array. I still able to see the webvies at `chrome://inspect/#devices` and can connect.

Does anyone have an idea why i only get an empty array or know an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I have found the problem. The app I control no longer uses a webview but a browser popup, so it can't be found via the search with webview.